# Convert ASCII code to equivalent character

Tags: apex

I am using the charAt(integer) method which returns the ASCII code as integer. How to convert that ASCII code to it's original character in "Apex"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
String myChar = String.fromCharArray( new List<integer> { 65 } );
```

`myChar` is 'A' now.

Comment: Hey, how can I get exactly reverse of this
Like -- 65 => 'A'

Comment: @OmkarDeokar see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85495/string-to-ascii