# String to ASCII

Tags: apex, string

How can i convert (in APEX) a String to an Integer, which corresponds to its ASCII.

**What I have:**

String Name = 'A';

**What I want:**

Integer Number = 65;

**Thanks all!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string.getChars() method works for this:

```
Integer[] vals;
String tmp = 'This is a test';
vals = tmp.getChars();
```

Documented in the official documentation in SF with an example of doing just this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_getChars